# add row to declarated table sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I add row to my table in database, use the sqlalchemy?
I use next code:

```
   for i in range(count):
        name = Utils.uniqID()
        class name(Base):
            __tablename__ = name
            first = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
            second = Column(String)
            third = Column(String)

            def __init__(self, first = None, second = None, third = None):
                self.first = first
                self.second = second
                self.third = third

        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I'm trying to add rows with next code:

```
def insertRandomRows(engine, table, count):
    rows = []
    for i in range(count):
        rows.append(table('af', 'adf', 'adf'))
    sessionmaker(bind = engine)().add_all(rows)
    enter code here
```

But they hasn't appeared in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
def insertRandomRows(engine, table, count):
    rows = []
    for i in range(count):
        rows.append(table(randstr(), randstr(), randstr()))
    session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)()
    session.add_all(rows)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```